# Subir múltiples imagnes a Firebase con ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

Lo que quiero hacer es que luego de que se hayan subido todas las imágenes al storage de firebase me permita habilitar el botón de cargar el posteo pero siempre me da el 100% antes de que terminen de subirse todas las imágenes
La ide es que se haga el setProgress luego de que esten todas subidas

```
const fotoUpload = (ev) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < ev.target.files.length; i++) {
            const files  = ev.target.files[i]
            console.log(files.name);
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`fotos/${files.name}`);
            var uploadTask = storageRef.put(files);
            var picture = []
            
            storageRef.put(files).then(data => {
                data.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                    picture.push(url);
                    setFormulario({
                        ...formulario,
                        picture
                    })
                });
            });
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
                var progreso = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                setProgress(progreso)
            })
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el sdk de firestorage no tiene metodos para subir mas de un archivo ni tampoco para medir el progreso de multiples task. Lo que podrías hacer es mostrar un progeso de este tipo:

```
const fotoUpload = (ev) => {
    const n = ev.target.files.length
    var uploadedFiles = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const file = ev.target.files[i]
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`fotos/${file.name}`);
        storageRef.put(file).then(data => {
            uploadedFiles++;
            setProgress(uploadedFiles / n * 100);
        });
    }
}
```